# Error while training spaCy 3.0 model using project.yml file

Tags: python

I am building a ner model using spaCy 3.0 for a client. All the specifications related to the model execution happens through project.yml file which exists in my project root folder. When I execute the model from CLI using the command `python -m spacy project run rerun-training --force`, all the steps run but training step fails with the error 'permission denied in training/model-best folder'.
Btw, rerun-training is one of the workflows in thr project.yml file. I am working in a client environment where I cannot launch anaconda prompt in administrator mode. Is there a way to solve this problem?